# No funciona document.locattion.href en javascript

Tags: javascript

La idea es que, en una página que contiene un formulario, se redireccione de la página actual a la página principal cuando este sea rellenado. El problema es que se queda en la misma página.
El código en javaScript es el siguiente:

```
function crearSesion(){
var user=document.getElementById("usuario").value;
var pass=document.getElementById("clave").value;
  if(user!==""&& pass!==""){
    if(user=='julio_godoy_mu@hotmail.com' && pass=='javascript'){
       sessionStorage.setItem("user2",pass);
       alert("ingresado correctamente");
       document.location.href="index.html";
    }else{
        alert("no estas registrado");

    }
   }
}
```

El llamado a la función desde código HTML5 es el siguiente:

```
     <input onclick="crearSesion();"type="submit" value="iniciar sesion" id="enviar">
```

Desde ya muy agradecido.

Comment: ¿Te da algún error en consola? ¿Sabes seguro si entra en la parte del condicional en la que se hace la redirección?

Comment: entra, de hecho aparece el alert que tiene el mensaje:"ingresado correctamente"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

El botón hace un `submit` y creo que no deseas que lo haga. Por ello deberás cambiar el `type` y pasarlo a `button`

```
<input onclick="crearSesion();"type="button" value="iniciar sesion" id="enviar">
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, justamente ese era el problema

Comment: O capturar el event y hacer un event.preventDefault

Answer (score 6):

Lo mejor es separar el codigo JavaScript del HTML, es decir, no llamar funciones dentro del propio codigo HTML.

Como un ejemplo, partiendo del siguiente formulario en HTML.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Formulario</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css" type="text/css"/>    
    <!--LLAMAMOS AL SCRIPT DE JAVASCRIPT PARA VALIDAR ESTE FORMULARIO-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<fieldset>


    <div>
        <!--En este caso el formulario llevará a google, 
        pero en tu caso puede ser la ruta a "index.html"-->
        <form id="formulario" action="http://www.google.es" method="get">

            <!--Campos del formulario-->
            <p>Usuario:</p>
            <input type="text" id="usuario">
            <p>Contraseña:</p>
            <input type="text" id="password">           

            <br><br>

            <!--Boton enviar-->
            <button id="enviar" type="submit">Enviar</button>

        </form>


    </div>
</fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

Se podría validar perfectamente el formulario de la siguiente manera, así separarías lo que es el código HTML del código JavaScript.

```
//Con la siguiente linea, cuando se cargue la página se llamará a la función incio()
window.onload = inicio;




/*Funcion que se ejecutará cada vez que se cargue la página*/
function inicio(){

    /*Para no llamar las funciones en el codigo HTML
    lo mejor es hacer un evento cada vez que se pulse
    el boton de "enviar" del formulario. 
    Este evento ejecutará la funcion "validar()" */
    let a = document.getElementById("enviar").addEventListener("click",validar,false);



}


/*Funcion que se ejecutará cuando se pulse el boton enviar, 
se le pasa como parametro el mismo evento*/
function validar(evento){   

    /*Si el usuario y la contraseña es valida, retornará true*/
    if(validarUsuario() && validarPassword()){

        /*En este apartado puedes introducir el codigo 
        que quieras que realice el programa 
        cuando se consigue el login */

        //sessionStorage.setItem("user2",pass); por ejemplo. 

        /*Hay que recordar que tienes que obener del html la
        contraseña si quieres trabajar con ella, 
        como se ha hecho en la funcion "validarPassword()" */


        return true;
    }else{
        /*Si no es valido el usuario y la contraseña, 
        se cancelará el envio del formulario.*/
        evento.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
}


/*Funcion que valida el usuario*/
function validarUsuario(){
    /*Obtengo el campo "usuario" del formulario */
    let campoUsuario =document.getElementById("usuario");
    /*Obtengo el usuario. 
    (Es decir, el valor que se ha introducido en el campo usuario)*/
    let usuario = campoUsuario.value;

    /*Si el usuario es el indicado, retorna true*/
    if(usuario=="julio_godoy_mu@hotmail.com"){
        return true;
    }else{//Si no, retorna false.
        /*Mostramos una alerta */
        alert("Usuario incorrecto");
        return false;        
    }

}

/*Funcion que valida la contraseña */
function validarPassword(){
    /*Obtengo el campo "password" del formulario*/
    let campoPassword = document.getElementById("password");
    /*Obtengo la contraseña*/
    let passwd = campoPassword.value;


    /*Si la contraseña es la indicada*/
    if(passwd=="javascript"){//retorno true        
        return true;
    }else{//retorno false
        //Muestro una alerta
        alert("Contraseña incorrecta");
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Gracias muy completa tu respuesta, gracias